# PowerPoint multimedia type is not being published to the file system

Tags: content-manager, multimedia

We've got a Document schema which enables us to load different multimedia types (i.e. PDF, Word, Excel etc.) We've created many different multimedia types. Each component is running the default "Publish binaries for component" TBB.

My question is why is the PowerPoint document type is not being rendered on the page (i.e. if you click a link to the document it will download the PowerPoint document).

Things that I've done:

- Checked that PowerPoint is included in the Multimedia Types.
- Checked that the PowerPoint Multimedia Type has "application/ms-powerpoint" for it's MIME Type and "ppt,pps,pptx,ppsx" as it's File Extensions.
- Checked that the PowerPoint multimedia type is included as an Allowed Media Type within the Document schema.
- I ran a component template that takes a document schema as one of it's field and ran it through Template Builder to ensure that bytes are generated for it's size. A byte is generated suggesting that content is in place.
- Confirmed that the component template is running the default "Publish binaries for component"
- Checked IIS that it's returning the correct MIME Type and it is.
- Checked IIS after publishing the page containing the component holding different documents. PowerPoint is not present while Word, PDF, Excel are generated.

Am I missing something else entirely? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your Deployer's cd_storage_conf.xml. It may have some setting making the PPTs go elsewhere.

Comment: The cd_storage_conf.xml doesn't specify anything regarding PowerPoints. I'm going to check if the multimedia content is in the Broker DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The published multimedia content exists in the Broker DB under BINARY_CONTENT table. I've confirmed this by querying for content by their Publication Id and Type.

This suggested that the image is not being served by IIS or resolved through the web app. I've already confirmed that IIS serves the appropriate file so it's likely done through the web app.

We're using DD4T along with our Tridion solution and there's a "BinaryUrlPattern" within the web.config. We've updated the regex before so that only specific file types are rendered. This was missing the file extension for a PowerPoint document. Add those fixed the issue.